# Open Ai mujoco worldgen

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api

After running command  `./bin/examine.py examples/simple_particle.py` i get that error: `NO MODULE NAMED MOJUCO` .
I use this repository: https://github.com/openai/mujoco-worldgen i don't edited nothing just i runned terminal Commands: `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt` and `pip install -e .`

thanks for all help.

Comment: To get an answer to y our question, you will almost certainly need to edit your question to give more details, specifically a [mcve] showing how to reproduce the problem.  You wrote that `./bin/examine.py examples/simple_particle.py` generates this error, but what are `examine.py` and `simple_particle.py`? Are they part of some framework you are using?  If so, please [edit] your question and [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) it with the appropriate framework tags, the general tags you are using are unlikely to attract an answer.  See [ask].

Comment: But maybe [OpenAI gym mujoco ImportError: No module named 'mujoco_py.mjlib'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45263566) is related somehow?